# Combine tables' fields in Hibernate entity

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, orm

I'm currently developing a system where users can add any number of skills to their profiles and also assign a rating to each of them showing how advanced their abilities are. The system also allows them to add a description.

These are my database tables. A skill's name can be a programming language or other related things.

This is a Spring MVC project with Hibernate. The ID's in the skill_user table are foreign keys to the other two tables. A user can have 0-* skills and a skill can be assigned to 0-* users.

user

```
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | smallint(6) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| email      | varchar(75) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| password   | varchar(64) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| permission | tinyint(4)  | NO   |     | 1       |                |
| verified   | tinyint(1)  | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| blocked    | tinyint(1)  | NO   |     | 0       |                |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

skill

```
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id              | smallint(6) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name            | varchar(45) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

skill_user

```
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| user_id    | smallint(6)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| skill_id   | smallint(6)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| rating     | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| descripton | varchar(250) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Please note that skill_user has a number of fields in addition to the foreign keys.

**Now, I'd like a Java class as a model for Hibernate but prefer to not create a separate model for skill_user. That would allow me to manage the skills from the user class, as ideally my User class has the following methods:**

```
void addSkill(Skill s)
Set<Skill> getSkills()
void setSkills(Set<Skill> s)
```

Getters and setters for the rating and description would be provided in the skill model.

Hopefully my explanation is clear and any help on this is appreciated.

Thanks in advance for your answers and please do ask if more information is needed.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a **join table** inside skill.hbm.xml to perform this task.Below I have mentioned a way through to a solution.

> Skill.java

```
public class Skill  implements java.io.Serializable {
  private Integer id;
    private String name;
    //defining a set of users
    private Set<User> users = new HashSet<>();

    public Set<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public void setUsers(Set<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }

    public Skill() {
    }

    public Skill(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

> Skill.hbm.xml

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="your_package_name.Skill" table="skill" catalog="skillDB" optimistic-lock="version">
        <id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="id" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <property name="name" type="string">
            <column name="name" length="45" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <!--join table will automatically created by this...-->
        <set name="users" table="skill_user" cascade="save-update">
            <key column="skill_id"/>
            <many-to-many class="your_package_name.User" column="user_id"/>
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

> Perform Inserting data to the DB :

```
Session s = util.HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        s.beginTransaction();
        User u = new User("johndoe@gmail.com","123456",true,true,true);
        s.save(u);
        Skill skill = new Skill("Programmer");
        skill.getUsers().add(u);
        s.save(skill);
        s.getTransaction().commit();
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I'm trying to solve this using a minimal amount of XML. Is there a way this can be accomplished through (preferably) pure Java? Thank you again for your time!